# Need to get IP address to add to GAE blacklist

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ip, blacklist, denial-of-service

I'm getting a lot of requests to my appengine app from a malicious user and I suspect it might be an attempt at a DOS attack. I need to add thier IP address to blacklists on GAE. However when I look at 

`self.request.remote_addr`

all I get is my own IP address. How can I get the remote IP of the client that is actually sending me these requests?

Comment: Why don't you look in the Administration Blacklist panel? There's a list of the top visitors by Ip.

Comment: What do you mean "my own IP address" - the one of your home machine, or the one of the App Engine app? If the former, that's because your examining requests you yourself made.

Comment: Interesting point Nick. I never thought of that. I just looked at the logs for another app that I have on GAE, and the IP address is different, even though I'm accessing both (apps) from the same machine. Does this mean that the GAE logs are displaying the IP for the app and not for the user's machine? If that's the case, then how can I get a hold of the user's machine IP address, which is really what I need to add to the blacklist?

Comment: @systempuntoout the Administration Blacklist panel is showing my (app) IP and not my machine IP address - which I verified with: print socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

Answer (score 1):

You could see the IP on the Logs page in the admin panel. Click the 'plus' icon next to a log item in order to expand it and view request data.